# Extending the $\bar \partial$-Poincaré Lemma by using a partition of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-manifolds

Let $U$ be a disc (of possibly infinite radius) in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $U$ has the following property:

> **(P)** For every $g \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$, there is an $f \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f = g$.

Does the argument **(A)** below establish the property **(Q)** of $U$?

> **(Q)** For every $g \in C^{\infty}(U)$, there is an $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f = g$.

---

**(A):** Let $\mathcal{U} = \lbrace U_i \rbrace_{I}$ be a locally finite open cover of $U$ such that each $U_i$ has compact closure. Let $\lbrace \phi_i \rbrace$ be a $C^{\infty}$ partition of unity on $U$ such that $\text{supp}(\phi_i) \subset U_i$ for each $i \in I$. Denote $g_i:=\phi_i g$.

By **(P)**, there are $f_i \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f_i = g_i$ on $U$.

It is meaningful to write $g = \sum_i g_i$ on $U$, since $\mathcal{U}$ is locally finite. Set $f := \sum_i f_i$. We confirm the equation in **(Q)** at a point $x \in U$. Note that $x$ has a neighborhood $V$ such that, for a fixed subset $I_x \subset I$, we have:

- $f(y) = \sum_{i \in I_x} f_i(y)$ for all $y \in V$
- $\sum_{i \in I_x} g_i(x) = g(x)$

Thus:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}(x) = \sum_{i \in I_x} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \bar z}(x) = \sum_{i \in I_x} g_i(x) = g(x)$$

---

The question is, once again: Does the argument **(A)** establish the property **(Q)** of $U$?